# Java Primitives and Primitive Wrappers

Tags: java, garbage-collection, heap-memory

I am trying to understand how Java primitives and wrappers work. Let us consider the following example.

```
Integer sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
    sum += i;
}
```

Since Integer is immutable and a non-primitive, the statement `sum += i` will be compiled as the following

```
sum =  new Integer(sum.intValue() + i).
```

This would create around 10000 Integer objects (every call to new `Integer`) and the cost of `sum.intValue()` of unboxing the Integer to int.

Am I right?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Why do u need a wrapper class here, unnecessar overhead of unboxing, etc. Read this: http://brian.pontarelli.com/2004/07/15/jdk-5-auto-boxing-best-practices/

Comment: @sanbhat the question is about the efficiency and memory consumption of Boxed primitives.

Comment: Actually it is not `new Integer(int)` but `Integer.valueOf(int)`. The latter function has a cache. If not found than the constructor is used.

Answer (score 6):

Not exactly.  In fact:

```
    sum += i;
```

is equivalent to

```
    sum = Integer.valueOf(sum.intValue() + i);
```

For small integer values, `Integer.valueOf(int)` will return a cached `Integer` object.  That means that you will get somewhat less than 10,000 new `Integer` objects created.

But "small" typically means -128 to +127 (IIRC) ... so the difference won't be significant.

---

As Louis Wasserman points out,object allocation is cheap, and garbage collection of objects that "die young" is even cheaper.  Nevertheless, you shouldn't use primitive wrappers unnecessarily, and especially not in code like this.

Comment: True but in case of such loop there wont be many cached objects and would create new ones. Am I correct?

Comment: Yup.  Mind you, objects (especially quickly discarded ones) are cheap, but yes.

Answer (score 2):

No it's not like that. The compound assignment operator `E1 op= E2` is equivalent to `E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2))`, with the difference that `E1` is only evaluated once.

From [JLS Section 15.26.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2):

> A compound assignment expression of the form E1 op= E2 is equivalent to E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2)), where T is the type of E1, except that E1 is evaluated only once.

So, a binary operation is performed between an Integer reference and a primitive type. In which case, the Integer reference will be unboxed, and operation will be performed, and value will again be boxed to `Integer` reference. As from [JLS Section 5.6.2 - Binary Numeric Promotion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2):

> If any operand is of a reference type, it is subjected to unboxing conversion (§5.1.8).

So, no a new Integer object is not necessarily created. The expression in your loop is evaluated as:

```
Integer sum = Integer.valueOf(sum.intValue() + i);
```

And the `valueOf` method may use some cached value of `Integer` object(for some range).

---

Having said all that, I hope you are not literally using a wrapper type like that in your original code, but just for the understanding purpose. You don't need to use wrapper type, unless you really need it, and that would be rare case.

Comment: Right, but still there is no need of using wrapper class in the shared code. Uncessary overhead of unboxing and auto boxing.

Answer (score 2):

[Prefer primitive types over Boxed types when using Loop](http://paulgrenyer.blogspot.in/2009/10/item-49-prefer-primitive-types-to-boxed.html)

Yes you are correct the process of boxing and unboxing, especially in a loop can serious impede performance.

But in your case you are just looping and you should **NOT** be using boxed primitive here and rather use `int`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, almost 10000. This is a decomiled .class

```
    Integer sum = Integer.valueOf(0);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        sum = Integer.valueOf(sum.intValue() + i);
```

Integer.valueOf has a cache for small numbers, -128 to 127 by default, so actually 10000 - 128 Integer instances will be created