# Error while attempting null check

Tags: java, collections, int

I am checking for null before doing a certain operation but I have run into some issues. Following is the code:

```
if (c != null && c.size() != null) {
    if (c.size() > 0) {
        return (Application) c.toArray()[0];
}
```

I am getting a *'The operator != is undefined for the argument type(s)int, null'* at the point 
 c.size() != null. I understand the return type for the size method is an integer, is that why I am getting this error? Hope someone can advise. Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't the error tell you all?

Comment: `int` is a primitive type, and doesn't have `null` that is why is complaining so that condition is unnecesary. In fact as is not a reference to an object it can't be null.

Comment: c.size() returns an int. You cannot compare an  int(primitive type) with null. Also, the inner if(c.size()>0) is also redundant as you ahve already done the size check in the previous if statement.

Comment: learn more about [primitive datatype](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) `.size` will never return `null`, the default value of `int` is `0`. so you should change `null` to `0`

Answer (score 0):

`int` is a [primitive type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) and is not an `Object` so is not a reference that can be `null`. Read more in this previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19511689/2415194)

Then in your code just remove that condition.
And also is preferred you use `c.isEmpty()` rather than `c.size()>0`

Your code would look like this:

```
if (c != null && !c.isEmpty()) {
    return (Application) c.toArray()[0];
}
```

Comment: Hi, if c happens to be null, that would mean it's also empty right?

Comment: @JohnJava Not, if `c` is null  means that the reference `c` is not pointing to any object, so if you make `c.isEmpty()` will throw `NullPointerException`

Comment: Thanks nachok, what about a scenario like this
List<someStuff> list
 and I do a if if (list != null), there would not be a need for me to also do a list.isEmpty() right? since list in this case is an obj ref variable.

Comment: @JohnJava No!! `list` is just a reference(like a pointer) that refers to an Object of Type(LIST), if it's not pointing to anywhere then `list` is null, but if it's pointing to a `List` then could be empty or not.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the result of `c.size()` is an integer. An `int` is a primitive, and it *cannot be `null`*. Only objects can be `null`.

Second, `c.size()` will *never* return `null`, so the check

```
c.size() != null
```

is unnecessary.

**Note:** There are wrapper classes for each primitive type. For example

```
Integer i = 4;
i = null; // valid
```

That assignment will be valid because `i` is an instance of the class `Integer`.