# Boxing of null value is allowed then why unboxing is not allowed?

Tags: java, null, boxing

I was reading [jls §5.1.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) and it says that there are 9 types of boxing, 9th one being Boxing `From the null type to the null type`

Then I read that [Unboxing Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8) of `null` throws a `NullPointerException`. Ok that is obvious. **Then why boxing of `null` does not throws a `NullPointerException`and what is the use of boxing `null` value?**

Comment: How can you have a primitive null?

Comment: I think its not about primitive null, we can have boxing for null type to null type as jls said. My question is what is the use of boxing null and why it does not throw NPE.

Comment: The answer is in the link you gave `This rule is necessary because the conditional operator (§15.25) applies boxing conversion to the types of its operands, and uses the result in further calculations.`

Comment: Because there is nothing to unbox.

Answer (score 1):

Converting `null` to Integer does not throw `NullPointerException` because `null` is a valid value for any reference, e.g:
`Integer intObject = null; // fine`

However, you cannot do this:

`int intPrimitive = intObject; // not fine`

Because when you try to convert an `Integer` to `int` the `Integer.intValue()` is called behind the scenes, but calling any method on a null reference throws NPE:

```
Object whatever = null;
whatever.anyMethod(); // always throws NPE
```

Because the reference points to `null`, not an actual object of the chosen type.

Comment: Not an answer. My question was for `Boxing` and `Unboxing` not reference type can have `null` values and primitive can not, I know this also have an answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19511616/why-java-does-not-allow-null-while-declaring-primitive-data-types

Answer (score 0):

I think the doc you provide give the answer. "This rule is necessary because the conditional operator applies boxing conversion to the types of its operands, and uses the result in further calculations."

If one of second and third operands of `?:` is not boolean or numeric expressions, then boxing may be used. For example, the type of `true?1:2` is `int`, while the type of `true?null:1` is `Integer`. In the second example, auto-boxing is employed. And in the run time, the second example's type will be null type because when boxing null type, a null type will be got.